# Is there any way to adjust column width in md-data-table?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I was working on an example for md-datatable found on [Git Hub](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) It worked well but when I tried to adjust thw column size as it consumes extra space in table th styling codes where overirdden by `md-data-table.min.css` file. Please help me to reduce the spacing between columns of table. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the less file https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table/blob/master/app/styles/app.less and try to alter everything under following selector (line 41):

```
md-toolbar.md-table-toolbar.alternate {
  color: #1e88e5;
  background-color: #e3f2fd;

  .md-toolbar-tools {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to reduce the space between the columns